# Handling 404's with non-redirecting pages that can't be "+1'd

Tags: url-rewriting, http-status-code-404, google-plus-one

I am using an .htaccess custom error page "error.php". Problem is, all it does is just redirect them.

I would like for my 404 to display the requested URL in the address bar, as if the user was never redirected.

Here are a few model examples:

http://us.battle.net/wow/en/22222222222222222222

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/222222222222222222222

Are these pages simply using a URL rewriter that is in actuality something like "domain.com/index.php?page=2222222222222222222222" ? If so, are they just printing out text without indicating that it is a 404 page without marking it as an error page somehow?

They have to be sending something in the header. I have a Chrome Extension for the +1 button, and when I go to the listed pages, it gives me an error saying "Cannot +1 this page."

Does anyone have any idea what "flag" is being used here?

Comment: Those page are 404, i assume you can't "+1" those page.

Comment: My error.php _can_ be +1'd, so I'm missing something...

Comment: If you use Chrome, you'll be able to pull out the developer tool, right? Under "Network", you can inspect the response code. It's a 404 in those cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can send HTTP status codes using the pre-processor which determines that the page doesn't exist. For example, in PHP you would use this:

```
header('HTTP/1.1 404 Page Not Found');
```

This would send the 404 header *along with* the custom 404 page you want to display. You can do this with any HTTP status code, even make up your own (though they probably won't be recognized).

```
header('HTTP/1.1 418 I'm a Teapot');
```

If you use Apache's `ErrorDocument` definition in your .htaccess file, it should maintain the error code so long as you do not modify the headers with the page defined (such as running a PHP file) or redirect to a new page. Using plain text and/or (possibly) a HTML file would preserve the 404 header. I have never tested it with an HTML file.

Comment: Chrome thinks my page is in a redirect loop when I try to add that preprocessor to my custom ErrorDocument. I am going to just have my PHP pages send the header along with "error" content using URL rewriting when the client sends invalid $_GET stuff.... that might be what I was originally trying to do.

Thanks, I didn't know you could send page content along with the 404 header, I thought the browser would abort loading when it got that.